# Why does approx return a list rather than a data frame or array?

Tags: r

It makes no sense to me that `approx` would return a list, since - if I understand it correctly - the two elements of the list that it returns are guaranteed to be numeric and of equal length. Given that, it would seem to make more sense to return an array or a data frame.

I'm writing some functions using `approx`, and this makes me thing that I don't fully understand how it works. Is there a situation in which a list is necessary, or better?

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but I'm failing to see why there's any real practical difference between the two options.

Comment: For the most part there's not a major practical difference between the two - except that data frames are easier to plug into plots in some cases. For me the bigger problem is that it is seems weird, which makes me think that I don't understand `approx` correctly, which could cause me problems later on.

Comment: `my_approx <- function(...) data.frame(approx(...))` (I do appreciate the caution in thinking that there might be some deep underlying reason why it's done this way. `approx.R` is prehistoric (the earliest available history is from 1998), so short of asking on `r-devel` and hoping R-core bites ...)

Comment: @BenBolker -- Or hoping they *don't* bite, as the case may be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions take pairlists as arguments. Generally lists are used to pass arguments to `lattice` graphics, which was the dominant high-level graphics environment before `ggplot` and descendants came along. Lists are also used to pass parameters to control arguments in many functions. In this case you would expect the `x` and `y` lengths to be the same, so it *could* be a dataframe, but there is no particular reason to demand such a structure,  and the base functions `points` and `lines` will accept named lists and properly allocate them to their argument lists.

(<strike>I do not think a matrix could get properly distributed to the x and y arguments of the base plotting routines even of there were row or column names that matched.</strike>  Matrices are really folded vectors.)

So I think the answer is that passing lists is most consistent with how functional programming is implemented in R.

Comment: yes, but ... two-column matrices, data frames, and lists with elements `x` and `y` all get handled correctly by most base plotting functions, thanks to `?xy.coords` ...

Comment: Well, dataframes _are_ lists, but ones with extra overhead. I see no reason that passing as a list is inferior. If you look at the `xy.coords` code you see that a dataframe would get handled by the same section of code as would a list.

Comment: yes, but it might nice to be able to ask for (say) `approx(x,y)[2:5,]` (i.e. index by row), which would be much more annoying with lists than with data frames.